# WordPress do_action function assistance

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to introduce myself to a Wordpress and after I installed the theme and went into it to do some edits, I found this call:

***\wp-content\themes\catch-everest\footer.php***

```
do_action( 'catcheverest_site_generator' );
```

I tracked it to this function and I am completely lost:

```
function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
    global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $merged_filters, $wp_current_filter;

    if ( ! isset($wp_actions) )
        $wp_actions = array();

    if ( ! isset($wp_actions[$tag]) )
        $wp_actions[$tag] = 1;
    else
        ++$wp_actions[$tag];

    // Do 'all' actions first
    if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
        $all_args = func_get_args();
        _wp_call_all_hook($all_args);
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
            array_pop($wp_current_filter);
        return;
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;

    $args = array();
    if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
        $args[] =& $arg[0];
    else
        $args[] = $arg;
    for ( $a = 2; $a < func_num_args(); $a++ )
        $args[] = func_get_arg($a);

    // Sort
    if ( !isset( $merged_filters[ $tag ] ) ) {
        ksort($wp_filter[$tag]);
        $merged_filters[ $tag ] = true;
    }

    reset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] );

    do {
        foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
            if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
                call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

    } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

    array_pop($wp_current_filter);
}
```

could you describe the data-flow in the case above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code looks quite complicated, but from a pragmatic point of view, it suffices to know that [`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) creates a hook, which allows you to execute code at a specific location, by hooking a function (using [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)). In your case, the theme author allows you to execute code in the footer. You could place following function in your `functions.php` file, or in a plugin. It will echo "Hello world" in the footer of your theme.

```
function my_site_generator(){
    echo 'Hello world';
}
add_action( 'catcheverest_site_generator', 'my_site_generator' );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an incredibly broad question that is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Actions and Filters, or Hooks, are the 'Wordpress' way of doing things. There is a loop on a Wordpress page that executes actions by priority, and then returns content which it will filter before it applies it to the page.

There are entire books written about Actions and Filters, and you should definitely check out some of the Wordpress Plugin books for more detailed information.

This book helped me a ton to understand what was going on when I was learning:

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development-Williams/dp/0470916222](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470916222)